# Blank PDF using getContentAsPDF in future method

Tags: visualforce, future, getcontentaspdf

I am having an issue in production with a specific Profile (a clone of the System Administrator) that generates Invoices via a @future call resulting in a blank PDF creation. Below is a simplified view of the code.

In the sandbox, the same User/Profile works correctly and I've compared the Profile and they are exact. Other User Profiles work correctly. The failing User has security access to the related VF Page and underlying controller. If that user requests the VF page via the UI via /apex/AR_Invoice?Id=XXXX the PDF is generated correctly and is not blank.

So it appears as though this particular user has this issue of a blank PDF only when its called via the @future method.

```
@future(callout=true)
public static void generateInvoicePDFs(Id voucherId) {
    
    PageReference pdf = Page.AR_Invoice;
    pdf.getParameters().put('id', voucherId);

    Blob body;

    // returns the output of the page as a PDF
    body = pdf.getContentAsPDF();

    System.debug('#### body size after getContentAsPDF ' + body.size());
}
```

Here are the related VF page attributes

```
<apex:page renderAs="pdf" controller="AR_InvoiceController" action="{!doInit}" applyHtmlTag="false" showHeader="false">
```

When this code is executed with the offending User/Profile, the body size is under 1KB, when it's run against a User that works, the body size is the expected 39KB. I also notice in the logs that there is no entry for the invocation of /apex/AR_Invoice that I see with Users that work.

So it's being treated as if it doesn't have access to it. There is no error either. And as mentioned above, the VF page (and resulting PDF) is successfully called via the UI.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the `<apex:page>` tag and attributes for the page you're using to generate the pdf?

Comment: Added tag and attributes